# JPArepository method with ManyToOne not return related data

Tags: entity-framework, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink, many-to-one

I have two entities using a OneToMany and ManyToOne relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TableName.PERSON)
public class Person {

@Id
@Column(name = FieldName.DB_KEY)
public String dbKey;

@Column(name = FieldName.ENTITY_ID)
public String entityId;

@Column(name = FieldName.SORT_KEY)
public String sortKey;

@JoinColumn(name = FieldName.ENTITY_ID, referencedColumnName = 
FieldName.ENTITY_ID, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinFetch(value = JoinFetchType.INNER)
public WLEntity entity;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = TableName.WL_ENTITY)
public class WLEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = FieldName.ENTITY_ID)
public String entityId;

@Column(name = FieldName.HAS_ADDRESS)
public boolean hasAddress;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity", targetEntity = PersonIndex.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Person> persons;
}
```

And a JPA-Repository defining one findBy... Method:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, String> {

List<Person> findBySortKeyStartingWith(String sortKey);
}
```

If I call this method I can see in the console:

```
SELECT t1.DB_KEY, t1.ENTITY_ID, t1.SORT_KEY, t0.ENTITY_ID, t0.HAS_ADDRESS FROM WL_ENTITY t0, PERSON t1 WHERE (t1.SORT_KEY LIKE ? AND (t0.ENTITY_ID = t1.ENTITY_ID))
```

So the join I want is correct executed, but in the returned data the entity field is still null but all other fields are filled:

```
List<Person> persons = personRepository.findBySortKeyStartingWith("Sort");
Person person = persons.get(0);
```

person.entity == null but person.entityId is correctly filled.

So what I have to do, to get person.entity filled?

I use spring boot with eclipselink jpa 2.6.4

Comment: Switch up your mapping so that insertable=false, updateable=false is on the entityId basic mapping instead of the JoinColumn.  If this resolves the problem, it was because this makes a mapping read-only, so the relationship isn't being set in the shared cache.  The other alternative is to force a refresh using em.refresh or by using an EclipseLink specific refresh query hint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I put insertable=false, updateable=false on the entity_id mapping I can't write the entity_id anymore. I also tried @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "org.eclipse.persistence.config.CacheUsage", value = CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache)}) on the query and in addition set PersistenceUnitProperties.CACHE_SHARED_DEFAULT = "false" in my JPAConfig, but this also not works.

Comment: If you can't write to the entity_id field in the DB, then you are not setting the relationship.  If you don't set it, it sticks in the cache with a null value until you refresh your object.  While you can refresh it, none of the settings you are using would do that (they affect the use of the shared cache, not the managed entity instance in the 1st level cache), and refreshing is expensive - why bother when you can just set the reference yourself?

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation and help. Now it works. I changed the  insertable=false, updateable=false like you suggerst in your first comment and also changed the insert logic. I now not insert for each table itself but entity and person together with on repository call. After that the query works.